# can't connect my compojure app to postgres db (following heroku tutorial)

Tags: clojure, postgresql-9.1, leiningen, compojure

i'm following along the [heroku compojure tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clojure-web-application#connecting-to-postgresql-with-clojurejavajdbc). When I get to the point in the tutorial where a table is created, I get the following error message:

```
user=> (require '[clojure.java.jdbc :as sql])
nil
user=> (sql/with-connection (System/getenv "DATABASE_URL")
  #_=> (sql/create-table :testing [:data :text]))
IllegalArgumentException db-spec postgresql://localhost:5432/lord is missing a required  parameter  clojure.java.jdbc.internal/get-connection (internal.clj:147)
```

I've tried adding the name of the linux user i created the db with and that users's password 
to the DATABASE_URL but no luck. I'm missing something here and i'm not sure what it is. Where is db-spec defined might be the right question but i'm not exactly sure.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the connection into a map like this (this is mysql specific but you get the gist):

```
  (def db-conn {
           :classname "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" ;must be in classpath
           :subprotocol "mysql"
           :subname (str "//" DBHOST ":" DBPORT "/" db-name)
           ; Any additional keys are passed to the driver as driver-specific properties.
           :user DBUSER
           :password DBPASS})
  (sql/with-connection db-conn 
    (sql/create-table :testing [:data :text]))))
```

Hope this helps.